# A graph can be partitioned into two cliques, given that any $k$-sized subgraph can be made by adding more than $k$ edges

Tags: graph-theory

I need to prove that a graph can be partitioned into two cliques given that any $k$-sized subgraph of the graph can be made by adding more than $k$ edges.

I've tried proving this inductively, but wound up completely stumped.

Comment: Hint: If we take the full graph $G$ to be our subgraph in the condition, what does this say about the average degree? In particular, there is a vertex connected to all but one other vertex; now try letting this vertex be the removed one.

Comment: Consider some partitioning of the other vertices into $2$ cliques. The removed vertex is adjacent to all the vertices in one of these cliques.

Comment: Yes, the induction is key for this to work. From a graph with $n+1$ vertices, we can find one with $n-1$ neighbors. Then, we use the fact that the $n$ other vertices can be partitioned into $2$ cliques, finishing with the above observation.